# How do you support different VR platforms?

Tags: unity, android, windows, virtual-reality, gearvr

I created an Android app for Gear VR in Java (using the GearVR framework) that I now want to port to Unity, so it can also be used for Microsoft's semi-new Mixed Reality headsets (for Windows; not HoloLens, though).

I've never worked with Unity (or C#) before, that's why I have a question:

How would you set up something like that? Can you simply create a single project and then put it on your (Android) phone/compile it on your PC depending on where you want to test it, or do you need separate projects for different platforms?

Answer (score 1):

> Can you simply create a single project and then put it on your (Android) phone/compile it on your PC depending on where you want to test it, or do you need separate projects for different platforms?

Yes, you can create a single project and build it for each platform you want to target. This is one of the major benefits / reasons to use a multiplatform game engine like Unity.

For a very simple project, this should mostly "just work" - you [select your build platform from the build settings dialog](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html) and you're off to the races.

As you start using more platform-specific libraries, tools, input conventions, etc. you might need to expand on this with things like native plugins, conditional compilation, asset bundles, or custom build scripts to control what gets included in each platform, or abstraction layers to keep the bulk of your game code & content cross-platform.

Andrew Carvalho of Laundry Bear Games gave a great talk about how to do this type of platform-specific work at EGLX 2018 - [I tried to capture some of the main points in a livetweet thread](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/1056625501652074496). Keep an eye out for the video of the session to get the whole story.

This work tends to be very bespoke for the type of per-platform adjustments a particular game needs, so if you find that you need more than what comes out of the box, you can post a new question here detailing the specific task you need to accomplish / build errors you're getting, and how you're trying to solve them, to get tailored help in making it work.

Comment: There may also be some differences in the android manifest if you want to support different VR setups (e.g. Oculus Gear VR vs. Google Daydream). I'm running into that headache myself right now.

Comment: If you have any tips to offer in an answer @Draco18s, I think that would be worth upvoting. I don't have any Android-specific VR experience to date, so I can't speak to those details myself.

Comment: I would...if I had the answers! Right now my project is in a state where it fails to compile and I have no idea what I did to break it.

Comment: I wanted to use Unity for Gear VR and MS's VR headsets and I probably do need one additional library but I have no idea if it's supported by both Android and Windows. So what you're basically saying is: Once you need specific additional libraries for different OS, better split the project into 2 to make handling everything easier... I already found the page you linked (but still thanks), unfortunately it doesn't really help with anything except building. @Draco18s What headsets are you developing for? The whole permission setup (Android vs. Windows) originally was my second question... *cough*

Comment: No, this is not what I am saying. I still recommend using one project, an using the techniques listed above to separate content/code/libs that need to be platform-specific within a single project. To get into details beyond the build settings, we'll need specifics about what code/content/lib differences you need in a particular situation.

Comment: The question is simply what's easier and if it ends up getting really messy because of having to distinguish between Android and Windows for everything, I'd rather have 2 projects. I'm not sure if Unity can even do what I need it to do without additional libraries (the GearVR framework can because of OpenGL ES), I'm going to open a new post for everything that I need building a mesh-wise tomorrow. Have you ever done anything for MS's VR headsets in Unity and do you know how controller input for a standard gamepad vs. MS's motion controllers is handled (separate or same for everything?)?

Comment: Don't forget that managing two projects is itself messy — that's why we have game engines and conditional complilation and all these tools to help us author the game once, then build for multiple platforms from that single common source. There's setup work to make it go smoothly, sure, but for many applications it will be less arduous than keeping two separate branches of your project in synch with each change or bug fix. That's a cost you have to keep on paying over the life of the projects, rather than investing in multi-platform support early.

Comment: @Neph Gear VR and Daydream, which complicates my own problems because they're *both Android apps.* Someone made a clever little "change the manifest" tool for the project (before I got here) and I did eventually discover the problem I was having with my build on Friday (some resource files in the wrong place: thanks documentation! You were oh so helpful at describing where they needed to go).

Comment: I would also suggest taking a look at the VRTK repository, even though its not longer funded (a travisty honestly) you can learn a lot about muti-platform setup for VR.